# how can create simple button in cakephp without html code

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3

I am new in cake php. i am creating a simple button by cake php code. but it make by default submit button. i dont want to use HTML code.

```
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->button('ajax_button');
```

Is there any way so that i can add simple button without using HTML. i mean by cake php code. above button code create a submit button

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
echo $this->Form->button('ajax_button',array('type' => 'button'));
```

Comment: @sandeepsoni  my pleasure